# fill a div with div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this example I use jquery to speed things up. But it's more about css.

I was wondering, is there any way possible to fill the container div with the content divs in such a way that i see as least kittens as possible.

html:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
   width: 640px;
   background-image: url('http://critterbabies.com/wp-content/gallery/kittens/Kitten-pic-cute-kittens-16292210-1024-768.jpg');
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
   min-height: 640px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
   background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

jquery/js for convenient sake:

```
randomColor = function() {      return "rgba("+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+"1)"
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var w = 160;
    var h = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    var color = randomColor();

    $newDiv = $('<div class="content">');

    $newDiv.css(
        {"background" : color,
         "width" : w,
         "height" : h
        });

    $("#container").append($newDiv);


}
```

Comment: this code did'nt worked fot you?

Comment: What do you mean with as least, as possible? 1 pixel?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

randomColor = function() {
    return "rgba("+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+","+"1)"
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 10) {
        var w = 160;
        var h = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
        var color = randomColor();
        jQuery('<div/>', {
            id: 'newDiv' + i,
            style: 'width: '+ w +'; height: '+ h +'; background: '+ color +';'
        }).appendTo('#container');
        i++;
    }
});


</script>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
   width: 640px;
   background-image: url('http://critterbabies.com/wp-content/gallery/kittens/Kitten-pic-cute-kittens-16292210-1024-768.jpg');
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
   min-height: 640px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
   background: blue;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

This produces the following ... not sure if this is what you wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change in the following the JS function as below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var w = 160;
    var h = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    var color = randomColor();

    $newDiv = '<div class="content">';

    $("#container").append($newDiv);


}
```

This will add the div dynamically .